# Pytorch: why does torch.where method does not work like numpy.where?

Tags: pytorch

In order to replace positive values with a certain number and negative ones with another number in a random vector using `Numpy` one can do the following:

```
npy_p = np.random.randn(4,6)
quant = np.where(npy_p>0, c_plus , np.where(npy_p<0, c_minus , npy_p))
```

However `where` method in `Pytorch` throws out the following error:

> expected scalar type double but found float

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this error, maybe it will be better if you could share a specific example where it failed (it might be the values you try to fill the tensor with):

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(4,6)
res = torch.where(x > 0.3,torch.tensor(0.), torch.where(x < 0.1, torch.tensor(-1.), x))
```

Where `x` is and it's of `dtype` float32:

```
tensor([[0.1391, 0.4491, 0.2363, 0.3215, 0.7740, 0.4879],
        [0.3051, 0.0870, 0.2869, 0.2575, 0.8825, 0.8201],
        [0.4419, 0.1138, 0.0825, 0.9489, 0.1553, 0.6505],
        [0.8376, 0.7639, 0.9291, 0.0865, 0.5984, 0.3953]])
```

And the `res` is:

```
tensor([[ 0.1391,  0.0000,  0.2363,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000, -1.0000,  0.2869,  0.2575,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.1138, -1.0000,  0.0000,  0.1553,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]])
```

The problem is caused because you mix data types in the `torch.where`, if you explicitly use the same datatype as the tensor in your constants it works fine.

Comment: by using `torch.where(x < 0.1, -1, 1)` you are replacing twice. The goal is to have only two numbers in the final result not 3 values as you have `0, 1, -1`. Please look at the example of the numpy case.